# Extra lines pre-appended to the file on httppost

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

Extra lines pre-appended to the file on httppost.

> **--O0sNZZ0ePHR0Rg-tonfSMTbakWL6aYsI1jlV^M Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="2016-09-13_23:54:23_123143_1896875081.xml"^M Content-Type: application/octet-stream^M Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary^M ^M**

```
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL);
MultipartEntity multipart = new MultipartEntity();
File file = new File(FOLDER_PATH + "/" + name);
multipart.addPart("file", new FileBody(file));
post.setEntity(multipart);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

What needs to be done to post file as it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the extra stuff, then you shouldn't be using a `MultipartEntity`. Rather you should be using `FileEntity`.

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL);
File file = new File(FOLDER_PATH + "/" + name);
FileEntity fileEntity = new FileEntity(file);
post.setEntity(fileEntity);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew it will be a very small issue but was unable to find.